# The link at woocommerce tag is no longer working

Tags: discussion

I understand that wordpress development SE doesn't welcome plugin question-- including woocommerce plugin. If you look at the [first page of woocommerce tag](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce), you will find that

> OFF TOPIC. Questions *specific* for this e-commerce plugin have their
>   own forum at https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce.

But the above https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce is a dead link, can someone fix this? Even though I can edit it, but I don't know what to put in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link is not dead and does point to the default WordPress support forum for the plugin.

[image]